# How to restrict Cut, Copy, Select & Paste option in Android when double tap or long click the edit text view?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to hide the copy,cut,select all and paste option when I double tap or long click the edit text view in Android application. I have checked several ways and the below is one of them that I checked. I also checked with  android:longClickable="false" and  android:textIsSelectable="false" in xml file. It needs to work in all the OS versions.Please check the attached screenshot.

[Check the options that is displaying when long press the edit text view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Apt4j.jpg) [Check the different options displaying when double tap the edit text view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcSax.jpg)

```
val callback: ActionMode.Callback = object : Callback, ActionMode.Callback {
            override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
                menu?.apply {
                    removeItem(android.R.id.copy)
                    removeItem(android.R.id.cut)
                    removeItem(android.R.id.paste)
                    removeItem(android.R.id.shareText) // Share
                    removeItem(android.R.id.textAssist)
                }

                return true
            }

            override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
                menu?.removeItem(android.R.id.paste)
                return true
            }

            override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {}
        }

        editText.setCustomInsertionActionModeCallback(callback)

        editText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(callback)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please check the attached screenshot for detailed information and I added additional information in description.

Comment: https://getridbug.com/android/disabling-the-context-menu-on-long-taps-on-android/

Comment: Hi GabeRAMturn. I am looking for Android[Kotlin] end code.